# Scala - Calculate maximum average between two lists

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am at the beginning of my Scala journey. I am trying to find and compare the average value of a given dataset - type Map(String, List[Int]), for two random rows selected by the user, in order to return the greater average value between the two. I can calculate the average for each row but I can't find a way to compare the average between the two rows.

I have tried in different ways, but I only get error messages. However the program calculates the average of each row

```
DATASET
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK3, 8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 6
```

This is how I the program calculates the average of a row

```
//Function to find the average
def average(list: List[Int]): Double = list.sum.toDouble / list.size

  def averageStockLevel1(stock1: String, stock2: String): (String, Int) = {
    val ave1 =  mapdata.get(stock1).map(average(_).toInt).getOrElse(0)
    val ave2 =  mapdata.get(stock2).map(average(_).toInt).getOrElse(0)

    if (ave1>ave2){
      (stock1,ave1)
    }else{
      (stock2,ave2)
    }
  }
```

This is how I have called the function in the menu

```
def handleFour(): Boolean = {
  menuDoubleDataStock(averageStockLevel1)
  true
}



 //Pull two rows from the dataset
  def menuShowDoubleDataStock(f: (String) => (String, Int), g:(String) => (String, Int)) = {
    print("Please insert the Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
    print("Please insert the Stock > ")
    val data1 = g(readLine)
    println(s"${data1._1}: ${data1._2}")
  }
```

error message

Unspecified value parameters: g: String => (String, Int)

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Check [ask].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code (and data if possible) as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: "I only get error messages" – Are you going to tell us what those error messages are? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Your usage of `if-expression` in `averageStockLevel1`  is wrong. It should be `if(avg1 > avg2)(stock1, avg1) else (stock2, avg2)`. In this scenario, you could calculate averages before the check.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unspecified value parameters: g: String => (String, Int)" tells you the following:

Your `menuShowDoubleDataStock` expects two parameters (`f` and `g`), but where you call it (from `handleFour()`), you only pass one value (`averageStockLevel1`) - that value is accepted as `f`, so the compiler complains that no value was passed for `g`.

Besides that specific error that the compiler currently complains about, there is also a second problem (which currently seems to be overshadowed by the one above): the type of `f` is defined as `String => (String, Int)` (a function that takes one String parameter), but the value that you are passing (`averageStockLevel1`) has the type `(String, String) => (String, Int)` (a function that takes two String parameters).

I'm not 100% sure if I understood what you are aiming to do, but I think the solution could be to change the signature of `menuShowDoubleDataStock` so that it only takes one parameter of type `(String, String) => (String, Int)`:

```
// make the user enter two stock-names and pass them into resultCalculator to
// get the result (and then print it)
def menuShowDoubleDataStock(resultCalculator: (String, String) => (String, Int)) = {
 print("Please insert the Stock > ")
 val stockName1 = readLine
 print("Please insert the Stock > ")
 val stockName2 = readLine
 val result = resultCalculator(stockName1, stockName2)
 println(s"${result._1}: ${result._2}")
}
```

Then calling `menuDoubleDataStock(averageStockLevel1)` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer has helped me solve the error. God bless you